# jquery removing a class from the first 15 elements in a large set efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to implement a pagination solution, where I query the server only once for all the items. This returns me 3000 items. I show the first 15 to the user, and then I show a more button. Upon clicking that, I want to reveal the next 15 items.

I tried this as follows:

```
 $(this).parent().parent().find('li.hidden').removeClass (index, classes) ->
   if index < 15
     'hidden'
   else
    ''
```

This works, looks awesome, but it iterates over all 3000 hidden items of course, and this causes a visible lag in the browser.

Then I considered using `.slice`, since this would make my code even more compact:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('li.hidden').slice(0,15).removeClass('hidden')
```

While this is compact, it has no visible speed-improvement, it still lags.

So I thought to be clever, and tried the following:

```
    all_hidden = $(this).parent().parent().find('li.hidden')
    for x in [1..15] by 1
      all_hidden[x].removeClass('hidden')
```

But of course that does not work, unfortunately (since the array operators does not return a jquery set, and using the slice operator to return a single element is not better at all then a single slice for 15 elements --I assume).

Do you know more efficient (faster) ways to remove a class from the first 15 elements in a set of about 3000?

Comment: Figure out where the slowdown is coming from. Is it from `.find('li.hidden')`? is `.children('li.hidden')` any better? As far as removing the first 15, the slice would be the most efficient way to reduce to the first 15

Comment: If `.slice()` is not fast enough, it would seem your problem is not how to take the first 15, but how _not_ to take all 3000 in the first place.

Comment: Why not just use AJAX?

Comment: Your issue is probably that your are doing client side pagination, perhaps it's best to do server-side pagination. Or a hybrid approach, where you buffer the next 100 records on the client

Comment: @cfs generally i'd agree, but it is possible to efficiently handle 500k+ records clientside smoothly. http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-optimizing-dataview.html

Comment: @billyonecan :lt will be slower, since it is a jquery extension and not a native CSS selector. See the "additional note" on the lt selector page: http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: 3000 is too many for one request. Split it into something more manageable, unless those entries are tiny.

Comment: We have a very specific backend, where it is much more efficient to retrieve all items at once, instead of really retrieving only the paginated blocks.

Comment: I'd suggest never having 3000 elements to begin with. Rather than showing and hiding elements, only have 15 on the page, and the rest stored as data internally.

Comment: The answer of @Alnitak got me thinking in the same direction as well. Since he proposes to add some extra housekeepign, I could as well only draw the 15 first, and add 15 more on request, instead of adding them all at once and unhiding them. Except I use handlebars and rendering them all at once was really easy :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using `.slice` to reduce a set of 3000 elements down to 15 is still too slow, then it would seem that your performance bottleneck is not in removing those 15 elements from the set, but in traversing the DOM to build the initial set of 3000 elements in the first place.

The only practical approach I can suggest is that you ensure that you only generate that set *once*, and then cache and/or manipulate that object as required for all subsequent operations:

```
var $hidden = $('li.hidden');   // do this once

function paginate() {
    $hidden.slice(0, 15).removeClass('hidden');
    $hidden = $hidden.slice(15);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am going to try this. Thank you for the suggestion. Since I have different blocks of data that can be paginated (building a facet browser and paginating the facets), so I will need a little more housekeeping to get this to work. I will keep you posted.

Comment: @nathanvda it would be easy enough to wrap the whole thing up in a closure that creates a separate list for each parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `less than` selector, see http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('li.hidden:lt(15)').removeClass("hidden")
```

Comment: I would be _very_ surprised if this is faster, because `:lt` is a jQuery pseudo-selector.

Comment: :lt will be slower than slice, since :lt is a jquery extension and not a native CSS selector. See the "additional note" on the lt selector page: api.jquery.com/lt-selector

Comment: That seems so obvious, but if you really think about what :lt(15) actually does, you'll see why this isn't going to be any better. :lt() is a jQuery extentsion, therefore jQuery will still have to select all 3000, it will then filter it down to the first 15.

Comment: actually yeah, thought about that too, but eventually it still might be a bit faster. how about a jsperf?

Comment: Unfortunately, since I really like the expressiveness of this answer, it has no visible effect. Sorry :(

Comment: @KevinB exactly, and I'm absolutely convinced that it's that initial selection of 3000 DOM elements that's causing the performance problem.

Comment: In this case it makes sense to only get all the 3000 entries once and use splice. But have a look at http://jsperf.com/jquery-lt-vs-splice

Comment: Slice is faster, but i'm surprised to see `li.hidden:lt(15)` being faster than splitting that up with .filter http://jsperf.com/selecting-first-15-of-3000-rows Either way this just confirms that the slowdown isn't in the filtering down to 15, it's in selecting the 3000.

Comment: So the conclusion would be that using `slice` or `less than` makes no real difference if you just want to get the first 15 elements, but for this case (where you want to get the first 15 again and again) @Alnitak's answer is much more preferable.

Comment: @KevinB using `.filter` still requires jQuery to visit every one of the 3000 elements and call a function on it _and_ determine that element's index.  I'm surprised it's not a lot slower!

Comment: @KevinB + @Alnitak: http://jsperf.com/selecting-first-15-of-3000-rows/2 shows me same speed for `slice` and `less than`. `.filter` being ~25% slower.