# jquery forcing a redraw in click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a click handler where I reveal the next 15 elements in a large set of elements, and this apparently takes time: it visibly lags, during which the user has no clue what is going on.

I am currently looking at two approaches to solve this:

- make sure we "unhide" the next 15 elements more efficiently  (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422634/jquery-removing-a-class-from-the-first-15-elements-in-a-large-set-efficiently)).
- make sure we show a spinner or something similar so the user knows "something is going on"

Now the problem seems to be, if I have a click handler as follows:

```
  $('#facets-list').on 'click', 'a[data-show-next-15]', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $(this).find('span.spinner').show()
    $(this).parent().parent().find('li.hidden').slice(0, 15).removeClass('hidden')
    $(this).find('span.spinner').hide()
```

all changes in the html are only visible until the handler is done. So the showing and hiding of the spinner is never done.

Is there a way to force a redraw somehow? While maybe not efficient, it will be much clearer to the user.

Comment: Your immediate problem can be solved by putting the line that unhides the elements inside a settimeout with an time of 1ms, but the true answer is that you want to cache the facets list once on page load and it shouldn't lag to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by @Paolo_Bergantino I came up with the following:

```
  $('#facets-list').on 'click', 'a[data-show-next-15]', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $(this).find('span.spinner').show()
    self = $(this)
    setTimeout((() ->
      self.parent().parent().find('li.hidden:lt(15)').attr('class', '')
      setTimeout((() -> $('span.spinner').hide()), 2)
    ), 2)
```

The spinner does not spin, but it is clearer something is going on now :)

Comment: This is more of a band-aid than anything, if you were to do something like `var $items = $(<selector for li items>);` outside the handler then slice that cached selector it would perform a lot better. You should also use `closest()` instead of `parent().parent().` as it reads better and is less likely to break if you move things around.